# Multiple jQuery plugins on multiple pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

My question may be very simple to most people on here. But i am very new to jQuery, and i am having a sort of difficulty with repetitiveness.

I have a custom script on a page which has a lot of text, that allows that text to be collapsed. This script is in jQuery. The page is in php.
I have multiple pages like this. I find myself having to place the code for the script documents on every page like this:

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/readmore.min.js"></script>
 <script src="javascripts/main_func.js"></script>
```

Is there a way that i can place it only on the index.php file and call the script function which is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.article').readmore({maxHeight: 640});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You might consider using [include](http://php.net/manual/es/function.include.php) of php

Comment: Do you have the three script lines in your `<head>` tag?

Comment: If you know that JavaScript is client-side code, then you'll know what you have to do.  Yes, the JavaScript needs to load every time a page is loaded.  There are lots of ways you can construct this without having to manually type the same code multiple times.  Google: "php include" which is something specific to your server-side language.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your page loads but this is what you would have to do essentially:

**index.php**

```
<?php
require('header.php');
require('content.php');
require('footer.php');
?>
```

**header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US" lang="en-US" >
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Page Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/default.css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/readmore.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascripts/main_func.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

**content.php**

```
<div id="content">
<!-- Do display code here -->
</div>
```

**footer.php**

```
<div id="footer">Footer Content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you have a new page, it would look something like this:

**newpage.php**

```
<?php
// Keep same header
require('header.php');
// New content page
require('newcontent.php');
// Same footer
require('footer.php');
?>
```